# I can't launch Chromium without --disable-web-security, how to fix?

Tags: launcher, chromium, .desktop

I launched chromium with `--disable-web-security`, and now whenever I click on the launcher icon in Ubuntu 16.04, Chromium launches with this option.

How to remove this option, to launch Chromium normally again?

Comment: Really sorry, I was mess up with all my questions. I ened up editing the content of the .desktop file to enable web security thanks to your answer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Quick & short answer

Chromium obviously created a local `.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications`, running Cromium with the option you mention (both Google-Chrome and Chromium are quite "productive" when it comes to producing local `.desktop` files).

Simple solution is to remove any local `.desktop` file(s) in `~/.local/share/applications`, referring to Chromium (you don't need them if you didn't deliberately create them locally), log out and back in before running Chromium again.

#### Note

`~/.local` is a hidden folder by default. Press while in your home directory (in nautilus) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to make it visible.

#### Background information

*Local* `.desktop` files overrule global ones in `/usr/share/applications`. If applications produce local `.desktop` files in `~/.local/share/applications` (some applications do), functionality may change, compared to the original one.

This obviously was the case in your situation.